# Am I allowed to use a domain name like macbookrepair.com?

Tags: trademark, branding, domain-name

If I were to register an available domain name like macbookrepair.com, do I have the right to offer commercial services from it, or does Apple have legal grounds to get the domain registration terminated due to trademark usage?

Does the fact that commercial services aren't hosted on the domain itself (and it redirects to a website without the trademark) affect the legality of the situation? Could Apple have a domain terminated for simply hosting a blank webpage? Am I allowed to sell this domain to other people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple lists [their trademarks](https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/trademark/appletmlist.html), which includes "Mac" and "Macbook". "Big Mac" (burger) does not conflict (also, Macdonald's got there first) because they are unrelated products. Your use is clearly in competition with Apple, therefore there is a reasonable chance that Apple would take action since your use is "potentially confusing" (it might imply that you are an Apple repair place). [Icann has a page](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/trademark-infringement-2017-06-20-en) explaining about trademark infringement, but ultimately this is a matter that gets decided by the courts – Apple cannot unilaterally terminate your domain, but they can start a process that results in the domain being terminated and perhaps you being financially penalized for infringement.